# Statik: Implement navigation from data/views

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website build via [Statik](https://getstatik.com/) (a static web site generator, build with python).

Now I'd like to build a navigation out from my existing `data` or `views`, via a property like e.g. `show_in_navigation = Boolean`. 
I thought about writing a custom template tag to get a list of all instances with `show_in_navigation = True` - but I don't know where to start or what would be the best approach in the first place;-)

My goal is a Twitter Bootstrap `navbar-nav` component filled with my `show_in_navigation` entries (with a bonus for highlighting the current page).

Any hints or tips?

My current implementation defines a `navigation_bar` variable in the main configuration:

```
# config.yml
context:
  static:
    navigation_bar: [['home', 'Home'], ['about', 'About'], ['contact', 'Contact']]
```

---

```
# templates/includes/navigation.html
<ul>
    {% for pk, title in navigation_bar %}
        <li {% if pk == active_page %} class="active"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% url pk %}">{{ title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

```
# templates/about.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% set active_page = "about" %}
```

... but that seems to be very verbose and not dry (e.g. repeating site titles, setting the active page)...